# Running Ant Filter Only on Non-Binary Files

Tags: ant

I'm using Ant's `<copy>` task to move the contents of one directory to another.  I'd like to use Ant's built-in filtering mechanism to replace tokens in the files I'm copying.

However, some of those files might be binaries, and I understand running the filter on them is a Bad Thing.  Is there any way to automatically exclude binaries from the files that get copied or filtered?  Or do I need to explicitly white-list the extensions for the files I actually want to filter on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitelisting would be the simplest solution. Otherwise implement a [custom selector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/custom-programming.html#customconditions) and use the same logic subversion does to decide [whether a file is binary](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#binary-files).

Atferwards use :

```
<copy todir="to">
 <fileset dir="src">
   <yourcustomselector/>
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

You may also use a [scriptselector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#scriptselector), see [some example](http://marc.info/?l=ant-user&m=118769231408319&w=2) i did with [jruby](http://jruby.org/) for inspiration